# Drupal identify user/browser

Tags: php, drupal, session

I am creating a setup, where I have multiple drupal websites running. I am working on a single sign on, but I want to check if the calls to my websites are made from the same person. Is there like a browser cookie or something with which I can identify a user ?

It's like a session identifier but across multiple websites.

Does anyone know what I can use for this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, by doing a redirect to one single website, which gives me an encrypted version of your session ID and then redirects you back to the website where you came from, where that key is stored in the local session of the SESSION

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Login Cookie](http://drupal.org/project/logincookie) module to set your own cookie

Answer (score 0):

If you are tying to do single sign on with Drupal I recommend looking at the [bakery](http://drupal.org/project/bakery) module. You may find that what you are looking for has already been implemented.

Comment: bakery is for subdomain levels, I want every website to be able to authenticate AND autologin on 1 single broker service, from any domain.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use PHPs standard session functions?

Comment: Every website would have it's own session